# Fastest way to find out in hibernate diff between database entries and entries stored within app

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, entity

```
@Entity
Student {
  Long id;
  String name;  
}
```

Let's say I have a list of 10 Students `List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();`  stored in a list somewhere in my app.

And I have a list of 20 entities I have stored in DB previously:

```
List<Student> studentsDbList = StudentRepo.findAll()
```

I would like to find out which of these 20 are not in the studentList, and delete them from database in the most efficient way without clearing whole db.
I can't find nothing similar on hibernate which allows me to do this with one method call, but I assume this is a trivial problem which has been solved numerous times, and I simply doesn't comprehend hibernate enough to solve it with some oneliner(
Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findAll() doesn't seem like optimal way and it's a code smell. I would only fetch  id's from db. Add this methods to student repository:

```
@Query("select s.id from Student s")
List<Long> getAllIds();

void deleteByIdIn(List<Long> ids);
```

Then make a diff on id's list and remove by ids:

```
ArrayList<Long> studentIdsToRemove = new ArrayList<>(studentIdsFromDB);
studentIdsToRemove.removeAll(studentIds);
studentRepo.deleteByIdIn(studentIdsToRemove);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter database entities by which are not in App and get the id of those Student those you want to delete using Stream API

```
List<Long> ids = studentsDbList.stream()
                               .filter(e -> !studentList.contains(e))
                               .map(e -> e.getId())
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then delete by ids from the database by using this on the repository

```
void deleteByIdIn(List<Long> ids);
```

And call with those student ids you want to delete

```
studentRepo.deleteByIdIn(ids);
```

*Note:* Override equals in Student class

Another better way is

```
List<Long> ids = studentList.stream()
                            .map(e -> e.getId())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

@Query(value = "DELETE FROM Student s WHERE s.id NOT IN (:ids)")
void deleteByIdIn(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

Comment: Btw, why ids? What is a difference with storing full entities instead? Memory?

Comment: Actually not storing id at all, get the ids to delete them.

Comment: And you can't delete them by entities that's why added another solve should work